# Converting Between British/American English

Tags: vim, nlp

I use Vim to edit my Latex document. Depending on the conference/journal I am submitting to, the university I am studying at, etc., I might like to convert from British English to American English or vice versa. Does anybody know if there is a plug-in to do that?

Comment: I don't know what the policy of your university or these journals actually is, but their policy certainly *should* be to accept the author's own spelling conventions, and not force them to adapt them. If it's really important to them, then they should take upon themselves to adjust them themselves, though I think wise policy would be to leave them as is, unless there's a pressing reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess that even if there were, it would be flaky and unreliable. Just like a spell-checker, such a translation tool cannot replace a good proofreader.

An example: US english is "license" for the noun or verb. British english is "license" for verb and "licence" for noun. The tool would have to do grammar analysis to get the correct results.

EDIT: not to mention problems with LaTeX commands such as `\begin{itemize}`...

Comment: Yes, definitely, I am not depending on it completely and stopping proofreading, but I believe it helps a lot. I was basically thinking of some dictionary out there to be used by some vim plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the best you'll be able to do is get it to flag up candidates for conversion, since there often isn't a unique spelling for a particular word. For example, the -ize and -ise suffices are actually both valid in British English, while only the former is in American English. Not only this, but the spelling of some words depends on grammatical context; e.g. practice/practise and licence/license in British English.

The process would require a pretty extensive dictionary of differences, due to the number of special cases, so building a Vim plugin would be a pretty lengthy task. Not to mention that Vim is primarily intended for editing source code rather than prose!

There are various tools on the net that you might be able to use, but I wouldn't rely on them too much:

- http://www.wyrdplay.org/spelling-converter.html
- [http://www.mywritertools.com/usuk.asp](http://www.wyrdplay.org/spelling-converter.html)